# Valgrind + C: conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, valgrind, cs50

I'm getting this error:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Which I take to mean, the value I'm using for a conditional statement is uninitialised. However, I believe the value to be initialised. I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. Help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is for CS50's week 5 assignment, to store a dictionary to which values can be added, and which can be used to check a text for spelling errors. I'm using a try to store the dictionary entries.

*edit*

Thanks to help I've received here I was able to solve the bug that appeared earlier. I've now changed the minimal example to more closely resemble the real case (now it takes the words values from a file called 'dictionary/small' rather than a hard-coded array), and I'm now getting another issue. 
Valgrind points to the line

```
if (word == NULL || strcmp(word, "") == 0)
```

in `bool add_word(char *word)`. It gives this error:

```
==5452== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5452==    at 0x4C2F1B1: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5452==    by 0x400B4C: add_word (test.c:81)
==5452==    by 0x400AA3: load (test.c:64)
==5452==    by 0x4008C6: main (test.c:26)
==5452==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5452==    at 0x4008E4: load (test.c:30)
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINES 45
#define LENGTH 143092

typedef struct node
{ 
    bool is_word;
    struct node *children[27];
}
node;

bool load(const char *dictionary);
bool unload(void);
bool add_word(char *word);
int char_to_child(char c);
char *strdup(const char *s);

node *root;

int main(void)
{
    load("dictionaries/small");
}

bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    char *words[LINES];

    FILE *fp = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    char buffer[LENGTH + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < LINES && fgets(buffer, LENGTH * sizeof(char), fp); i++)
    {
        words[i] = NULL;
        if (strlen(buffer) <= LENGTH)
        {
            words[i] = strdup(buffer);
        }
    }  
    fclose(fp);     

    // create a try and add the words
    root = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (!root)
    {
        return false;
    }
    root->is_word = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        root->children[i] = NULL; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++)
    {
        if (add_word(words[i]) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        free(words[i]);
    }

    return true;
}

bool add_word(char *word) {
    node *ptr = root;

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (word == NULL || strcmp(word, "") == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        int letter = char_to_child(word[i]);

        if (letter < 27)
        {
            if (ptr->children[letter] == NULL)
            {
                node *new_node;
                new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
                if (!new_node)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                new_node->is_word = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++)
                {
                    new_node->children[j] = NULL;
                }

                ptr->children[letter] = new_node;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ptr->children[letter]->is_word != true)
                {
                    ptr->children[letter]->is_word = false;
                }
            }
            ptr = ptr->children[letter];
        }
    }
    ptr->is_word = true;


    return true;
}

int char_to_child(char c)
{
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    {
        return c - 'A';
    }
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    {
        return c - 'a';
    }
    else if (c == '\'')
    {
        return 26;
    }
    else 
    {
        return 27;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point us to the offending line more explicitly than just giving a line number? Maybe say the function and the line.

Comment: Where is `root` defined?

Comment: *I believe the value to be initialised.* So is its value what you expect?

Comment: The line is this one: 
`if (ptr->children[letter] == NULL)`
It's in the `add_word` function.

`root` is defined in `dictionary.h`. I just added it to the original post.

I believe the value causing the problem is `ptr`, which is a pointer directed to `root`, which has the values:
`root.is_word = false` `root.children = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}`

Comment: It can't be `root.is_word` because `root` is a pointer (which should not be in a header file anyway).

Comment: Did you try assigning NULL in the declaration (`node *root = NULL`) ?

Comment: sorry, it should read `root->is_word` and `root->children` (I'm quite new to C :D)

Comment: Just tried it (`node *root = NULL`), still got the same error.

Comment: In general, you should try reproducing with `AddressSanitizer`. It is much faster and more accurate (for both false positives and false negatives) than `valgrind` ... it simply requires that you recompile all your code.

Comment: Do you suspect it might be a false negative?

Comment: this code block: for (i = 0; i < 27; i++)
                {
                    new_node->children[letter] = NULL;
                }` is setting only a SINGLE one of the children array to NULL.  Suggest replacing the 'letter' with 'i'

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)` the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` which is unsigned.  And that returned values is being compared to an `int` which is signed.  Such a comparison is problematic and should be avoided. Suggest: `or ( size_t i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)`

Comment: Using `size_t` seems to have solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I've now changed the minimal example to more closely resemble the real case (now it takes the words values from a file called 'dictionary/small' rather than a hard-coded array), and I'm now getting another issue. 
Valgrant points to the line `if (word == NULL || strcmp(word, "") == 0)` in `bool add_word(char *word)`. 
It gives this error: 
Use of uninitialised value of size 8

Comment: If you use the option --track-origins=yes, valgrind will tell you more precisely where the unitialised value is coming from. Also, it would be easier to give feedback if you include the stacktrace of the error, and not only the error msg. I suspect that you still have a problem because you are adding more words than you have read : the words array has max LINES entries, you add all of them even if the reading loop above stopped when fgets encounted EOF.

Comment: Hm, but I make the loop conditional on `fgets` returning a value. Does `fgets` continue reading even when it has come to the end of a file?

Comment: Well I appear to have solved the problem by cutting out the middle-man. Instead of loading lines from the file first to an array, and then from the array to the function `add_word`, I call `add_word` on each line as it is read from the file. I'm not getting the errors any more, but I'd still be curious to know why it wasn't working before.

Comment: The problem is not when you call fgets. This is correct. The problem is when you looped afterwards on the words array: only a part of the entries were initialised (according to the nr of successful fgets), but you were adding all words up to the max size

Comment: Oh yes, I see. When I loop through the array to call add_words, should I use the `sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[1])` as the upper bound?

Comment: The wrong condition is is i < LINES, it should be something like: i < nr_words_succesfully_read_by_reading_loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++)
{
    if (add_word(words[i]) == false)
```

will eventually read all of the first `LINES` entries in `words`. However in this earlier code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LINES && fgets(buffer, LENGTH * sizeof(char), fp); i++)
```

you stop when `fgets` fails, and if `i < LINES-1` at that point, it means some of the pointers in `words` remain uninitialized.  Then your valgrind error comes from `add_word(words[i])` with the uninitialized pointer.

To fix this you could initialize all the pointers first, or perhaps remember the value of `i` from the end of the first loop and use that same value to end the second loop.

BTW `if (strlen(buffer) <= LENGTH)` is redundant. The `fgets` call guarantees that already, since you specified a buffer size of `LENGTH`.